# Can't create a pseudo network interface on Debian 11

Tags: debian, iptables, route, netstat, ifconfig

I have a KVM based Debian 11 (bullseye) VPS with internet access on `eth0` network adapter. The public IP has been assigned by DHCP. The IPs and Routes are as what follows:

[ifconfig and iptable BEFORE adding new interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYc8D.png)

*Note: Due to hide my server IP, the public IP is masked in the images.*

Now, I created a `dummy` network interface named `eth1` and assigned a private IP address `(10.200.100.50)`:

```
modprobe dummy
ip link add eth1 type dummy
ip addr add 10.200.100.50/32 brd + dev eth1 label eth1
```

and also, added a new route to the iptable:

```
ip route add 10.200.100.50/32 via XXX.YYY.ZZZ.1 dev eth0 onlink
```

*Note: `XXX.YYY.ZZZ.1` is `eth0` default gateway.*

[ifconfig and iptable AFTER adding new interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gey5H.png)

**Now the problem is here**, I have ping with `10.200.100.50` but can't connect to the internet through it:

[PING OK BUT CURL NOT OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDzWI.png)

```
ping 10.200.100.50 (OK)
curl ip.me --max-time 20 --interface 10.200.100.50 (ERROR)
```

Please tell me where my misconfiguration is.

Comment: Could also be a misconception and an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your actual goal?

Comment: @A.B The question is very clear and there is no point of ambiguity in it. Please give constructive comments.